# Answer count is wrong (or just not updated)

Tags: bug

As you can see in the image below (taken from my account page on the Medical Science site), I have answered a total of two questions:
[image]

however, in my Stack Exchange home page, just one answer is counted:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: The list of answers on your profile for the group isn't necessarily complete. Mine shows 5 answers when I've actually answered 108. There's a link to click to see all 108.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didn't know that!

Comment: Here is [link to the answers' tab](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=answers) in the user's profile.